# Theory DLO, quantifier elimination

Tags: model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

The sentence $E$ is: $\exists x\,\exists y\,\exists z\,\forall u\,((x < y) \wedge (x < z) \wedge (z < y) \wedge ((u = z) \vee (u < y) \vee (u = x)))$. We can assume that the language $A$ contains constants $\top$ and $\bot$ for true and false, respectively. How to decide whether $\mathrm{DLO}\vdash E$ or $\mathrm{DLO}\vdash \lnot E$?

Comment: Well, is this sentence true in $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ or not?

Comment: Also, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write mathematical symbols on this site. I've edited your post to conform to this style (and for grammar).

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what DLO stands for?

Comment: The theory of dense linear order(DLO)